# Get a count after a specific date grouped by person

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet with dates in Column C, alphanumeric in Column E, and Employee Names in Column F. I am trying to figure out how to build a query to give me a count for each employee listed in Column F after a specific date, say 07/05/2022. I would like for the formula to be used in the "Count" tab. The link to an example sheet is here [Test Area](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CoT0xWBS5Cbi7K5woykCRUyeZX-CjMT1L1QZKssv5oo/edit#gid=1342495604)

Comment: "... after a specific date, say 07/05/2022" How many are they  ??  Do you need to count how many elements are in the found list or how many are the (unique) employes?

Answer (score 0):

This is the draggable formula  you need:

```
=if(C2:C="",,COUNTA(filter('BAY 1'!F2:F,'BAY 1'!F2:F=C2,'BAY 1'!C2:C>=A$2)))
```

[image: counta]

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11NI_agEUZaLMjCNIBOLyDcfWDoaJXZMYjn1QhnfF9x0/edit?usp=sharing) to your modified file

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. I would like to be broken down to show the totals for each employee on the list not just a total of what all employees on the list did.

Comment: try my file now

Comment: This looks like what I need! I will give it a try in a live environment and see how it pans out. Thanks!